# How to create a dropdown list with my database entries?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

What i'm trying to do is to create a dropdown with all my "Stations" from database and when choosing one to zoom on it on map.
I have just created a controller called AdminMapController with this code:

```
    public class AdminMapController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AdminMapController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public ActionResult GetListOfStations()
        {
            ViewBag.ListOfDropdown = _context.Stations.ToList();
            return View("~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/AdminMap.cshtml");
        }
        public JsonResult GetAllLocation()
        {
            var data = _context.Stations.ToList();
            return Json(data);
        }
```

and the View ( only the drop down test ):

```
    </style>
    <br/><br/>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)
            {
                <option value ="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <br/>
```

Funny thing that `GetAllLocation` method works properly, but `GetListOfStations` throws me the error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` with these being the "problems": `@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)` and `ViewData["Title"] = "Admin Map";`

Any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use this one in return Action:

```
var model = _context.Stations.ToList();
return View("~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/AdminMap.cshtml", model);
```

View:

```
@model List<Stations>
<div>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>--Select--</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option value ="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but i'm not sure how should i work with it in the foreach in cshtml.

Comment: It still doesn't work...i'm starting to think that the data is not coming from the database..

Comment: Yeah, i managed to get the data and it worked for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you want to keep no using a model in this case would be to use "ViewData" instead:

```
ViewData["Stations"] = _context.Stations.ToList();
```

And in the view something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Stations"] as IList<Stations>)
```

But I still think a model is more uselful in your case.
Use the ViewData for extra information that wouldn't be part of the model.

Comment: I did some research on ViewBag too, and it seems that maybe what you were missing might have been the "as IList<Stations>". Both ViewData and ViewBag should work

Comment: Yes, after a little research i found that i should be able to get the information with both `ViewData` and `ViewBag`, but for some reason none of them were working, so i had to redo my view and controller, because when i was sending the info to the view with `return View("path")`, the View wasn't getting the info as it should. But you're right, i didn't try `IList<Stations>`, because i supposed the ViewBag was doing the job. Thanks anyway for your help.